# Mongoose one to one query returning nulll

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to create two models, `user` and `child`, that are able to relate to each other. In the mongo shell I am able to query children with a `user._id` parameter and return an array of children whose `admin` property is the specified user. Additionally, in my node app, I'm able to query my db of children based on their other properties such as `name`. However, when I perform the following query, an empty array is returned. It should be noted that `user._id` property is the string of a user that is indeed an admin. Additionally, simply changing the query parameter to `name` and a corresponding value results in a successful query. Am I missing something obvious?

User.js

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
});
```

Child.js

```
var childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  Address:{
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
  Admin : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});
```

Query (returns `null`):

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
Child.find({Admin:ObjectId(user._id)},callback);
```

Parameters used in creation of child:

```
 { "Name" : "First Child", "Address" : "Sample Address", "Admin" : req.user._id }
```

Child Sample returned from mongo shell:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59519c30c904d23ea2e9f58f"),
    "Name" : "First Child",
    "Address" : "Sample Address",
    "Admin" : ObjectId("594d9e5f9d3b199b781015a3"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Sample Parent:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594d9e5f9d3b199b781015a3"),
    "name" : "User",
    "email" : "user@email.com",
    "username" : "user",
    "password" : "$2a$10$.o9k2yyUMlTpecKVkqWYr.Pg8TMCGIZrexHb3Ce//5ILpC9CDKEeS",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: can you share sample document?

Comment: You seem to have a basic misunderstanding here. Your query should simply be `Child.find({ 'Admin': user._id },callback)` For some reason you are thinking you need to address a property called `ObjectId`, but there is no such property, hence no result. That's just a "schema type" to say what type is stored, and not an actual document property.

Comment: The ObjectId function simply converts the user._id to the correct type. I've seen and tried ye code both ways to the same result @NeilLunn

Comment: Not in the way you are thinking it does. Besides, mongoose already casts the type for you, which is why you have the schema in the first place. If you tried it and get no result, then the value is incorrect. Or possibly the actual document has the wrong type. I've given you the "correct" query for matching the correct type. Show the actual document as viewed from the mongo shell, which will show us exactly what type the data is.

Comment: Furthermore, you only ever mention creating the "parent". Did you actually ever create the "child"? This is of course answered by actually showing the child document as requested.

Comment: @sidgate I've updated the question to include the requested documents.

Comment: @NeilLunn I did indeed create both parent and child objects.

Comment: What is the collection name you go that from in the shell? Is is "children"? Mongoose pluralizes collection names by default, you can override that with a third argument which names the collection explicitly. i.e `mongoose.model("Child", childSchema, "childcollection")` where I explicitly name as `"childcollection"` there. There is no other reason why the query I gave should not work, aside from inputs. Do a hard-coded test as `Child.find({ "Admin": "594d9e5f9d3b199b781015a3" },function(err, result) { if (err) throw err; console.log(result) })`. After you check the collection name of course.

Comment: The collection name is child, good suggestion though. I tested the query with the value hardcoded in and ended up with the same result. I'm baffled - as I wrote in my question, the query returns an object in the shell and other queries are functional in the codebase.@NeilLunn

Comment: @NeilLunn after resetting the collection name to something different and then back to what it originally was, the query works. If you'd like to post that answer I can mark it correct. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Done. Don't know who upvoted the other answer given, but they clearly did not understand the clear problem of not addressing the correct field name in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a misconception of how to address property in the collection as well as not understanding that the `ObjectId` type is in fact already defined in your schema, and as such mongoose will "cast" this to the defined type for you in a `.find()` operation, or similar operations that are able to reference the schema.

Therefore the correct statement should be:

```
Child.find({ "Admin": user._id },callback);
```

Things you need to be aware when doing this are:

- Make sure that your input's are valid and of the values you expect. It is always best to debug, by passing explicit values when you have a problem:

  ```
  Child.find({ "Admin": "594d9e5f9d3b199b781015a3" },function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err; console.log(result) 
  })
  ```
- Mongoose "pluralizes" the given model name when it determines the actual collection name to address. In particular, if you have data already defined which you then create a schema for at a later date, then you likely need to name that collection explicitly, since it may not be the same as what mongoose is choosing:

  ```
  mongoose.model("Child", childSchema, "child")
  ```

In that second case, mongoose would choose `"children"` by default, so the explicit name is needed to the actual collection when named differently. The common example here is a model `"Person"` would actually become `"people"`.

As a final note, it's a good idea to turn on "debugging" to see what Mongoose is actually doing when sending your queries/operations to MongoDB.

```
mongoose.set("debug", true)
```

Understanding these things is how you avoid future errors, and generally gain further understanding of how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo. Schema defines field as `Admin`, while you are querying with `admin`. Field names are case sensitive. Code should be:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
Child.find({Admin:ObjectId(user._id)},callback);
```

Comment: that was a typo but when fixed still has the same result

Comment: @PatrickConnors, can you share a sample document stored in db?